# Trying to make a controller with 3 parameters received from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, web-services

I'm trying to make a controller that receives 3 parameters. These 3 parameters are given in the URL.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetCompared(string TeamProject, string Project, string branch)
{
    return Ok(_BranchesCompareService.BrancheCompare(TeamProject, Project, branch));
}
```

When I call my controller on Postman with GET: `http://localhost:(port)/api/Compare/GetCompared?TeamProject=MyTM&Project=BlackList&branche=Develop`

I've received a message like:

> No HTTP resource found matching the request's URI 'http://localhost:11860/api/Compare/GetCompared?TeamProject=Airports&Project=Vueling.BlackListPassenger&brancheToCompare=Develop'.
>   No action was found on the 'Compare' controller that matches the request.

Any idea? Thank u!

Comment: in postman have you set GET or POST as request type?

Comment: @KevinShah GET request type

Comment: Show your route configuration.

Comment: In you postman request url the last parameter is "branche", and the parameter in your method is `branch`.

Comment: The request in your error says `brancheToCompare` - the request in your Postman says `branche` - the parameter on your controller says `branch` - something doesn't seem right ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route tag. Try something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Compare/GetCompared")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCompared(string TeamProject, string Project, string branch)
{
      return Ok(_BranchesCompareService.BrancheCompare(TeamProject, Project, branch));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adds the FromQuery attribute to the parameters:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCompared([FromQuery]string TeamProject, [FromQuery]string Project, [FromQuery]string branch)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the FromQuery attribute to the controllers parameters.

```
//  /[controller]/compare?TeamProject=xxxxx&&Project=xxxxxx&&branch=xxxxx
[HttpGet("compare")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCompared([FromQuery]string TeamProject, FromQuery]string roject, [FromQuery]string branch)
{
    return Ok(_BranchesCompareService.BrancheCompare(TeamProject, Project, branch));
}
```